# Concatenate two or more attributes of the same node of a XML by XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

XML to XML by XSL Transformation where I want to concatenate multiple attributes like:

Sample Case:

```
<Sample>
  <Date Year="2012" Month="9" Day="21"/>
  <Time Hour="6" Minute="6" Second="6"/>
</Sample>
```

Required Output:

```
<Sample>
  <Date>9/21/2012</Date>
  <Time>6:6:6</Time>
</Sample>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by extending the standard XSLT identity transform with extra templates to match your **Date** and **Time** elements, re-formatting them as required

For example, to match a **Date** element, with **Year**, **Month** and **Day** attributes, you would do this.

If you could guarantee all **Date** elements had the required three attributes, you could simplify the template match to just

```
<xsl:template match="Date">
```

You would add a similarl template for the **Time** element.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Date[@Year][@Month][@Day]">
      <Date><xsl:value-of select="concat(@Month, '/', @Day, '/', @Year)" /></Date>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Time[@Hour][@Minute][@Second]">
      <Time><xsl:value-of select="concat(@Hour, ':', @Minute, ':', @Second)" /></Time>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<Sample>
   <Date>9/21/2012</Date>
   <Time>6:6:6</Time>
</Sample>
```