# Concatenate the values of two attributes into one attribute for all nodes that contain both

Tags: xslt

I have XML like this:

```
   <Parent>
       <Elem1 Attr1="1" Attr2="2">
           <Elem2>
               <Elem3 Attr1="4" Attr2="5"></Elem3>
           </Elem2>
       </Elem1>
   </Parent>
```

and it should be turned into this:

```
  <Parent>
     <Elem1 Attr1="1+2">
        <Elem2>
           <Elem3 Attr1="4+5"></Elem3>
        </Elem2>
     </Elem1>
  </Parent>
```

The problem is that I don't know the names of the elements, that is, `Elem1` or `Elem3` in this case. I know is that elements must contain both the attribute `Attr1` and the attribute `Attr2` but not all such element names ahead of time.

I also know that parent element must have the name `Parent`, but children containing the attributes may be at any level, either immediate descendants or deeper in the parent tree.

The closest to the possible solution that I could find is this
[StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525143/concatenate-two-or-more-attributes-of-the-same-node-of-a-xml-by-xsl) but my XSLT knowledge is not good enough to try to adapt it to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@Attr1[../@Attr2]">
    <xsl:attribute name="Attr1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@Attr2"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@Attr2[../@Attr1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent//*[@Attr1 and @Attr2]/@Attr1">
        <xsl:attribute name="Attr1" select="concat(., '+', ../@Attr2)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent//*[@Attr1 and @Attr2]/@Attr2"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHM

Comment: It is a hard choice picking between two correct answers. I would have preferred this one because it is more elegant and complete w.r.t Parent node but was unaware that my environment doesn't support XSLT 2.0 to this day and should have tagged the question accordingly.
So I took into account that Michael's answer was earlier. Thank you.